# Is semi-direct product converted to direct product if the normal subgroup is the center of $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semidirect-product

Suppose $G$ is a group and $N$ is a normal subgroup in $G$. Also suppose $G=N \rtimes H$. I need to know, is this semi-direct product reduced to the direct product if $N=Z(G)$?

My initial guess is yes! But any detailed explanation will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Only of the action of $H$ on $N$ is trivial, surely?

Comment: @RichardMartin But if $N = Z(G)$ (or even $N \le Z(G)$) then the action of $H$ on $N$ is trivial, so the answer to the question is yes.